# simplejwt: 401 unauthorized on post request

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

serializer/login.py

```
class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data['user'] = UserSerializer(self.user).data
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        if api_settings.UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN:
            update_last_login(None, self.user)

        return data
```

viewsets/login.py

```
class LoginViewSet(ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I cant login with right credentials using post request, it says 401 unauthorized. but when I try to register or refresh token using post request (using the refresh token), it works fine.

serializer/register.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(UserSerializer):
    #making the pass min 8 charecter and max 128
    #and can't be read
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, min_length=8, write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password'] # 'bio', 'avater',

#used the create_user method that we wrote
        def create(self, validated_data):
            return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

viewsets/register.py

```
class RegisterViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        res = {
            "refresh" :str(refresh),
            "access": str(refresh.access_token),
        }
        return Response({
            "user": serializer.data,
            "refresh":res['refresh'],
            "token":res['access']
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

viewsets/refresh.py

```
class RefreshViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, TokenRefreshView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = ""

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # my custom apps
    'core',
    'core.user',
    'core.auth',

    #external packages apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "CoreRoot.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "CoreRoot.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
           'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core_user.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
),

'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':

['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.